# Yii: Multimodelform Extension - How to create more than 1 member

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, multi-model-forms

I'm using [Multimodelform](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multimodelform/) extension to create multiple model in a single form.
This extension is working great but unfortunately i would like more than 1 member instead.
I have tried it without success at all.

My problem is I could not make more than 1 member by this extension.

Here's my code :

**From Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
        {
                Yii::import('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm');
                $model=new Endheader;
                $member = new Enddetail;
                $member2 = new Enddetailnq; <-- i just ant to this new member.

                $validatedMembers = array();
                //$validatedMembers2 = array();
                // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                 $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['Endheader']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['Endheader'];
                   if(isset($_POST['sav'])){  
                        if((MultiModelForm::validate($member, $validatedMembers, $deleteItems) && MultiModelForm::validate($member2, $validatedMembers, $deleteItems)) && $model->save())
                        {
                                $masterValues = array('HEH_ID'=>$model->HEH_ID);
                                if(MultiModelForm::save($member,$validatedMembers,$deleteItems,$masterValues) && MultiModelForm::save($member2,$validatedMembers,$deleteItems,$masterValues))

                                    $msg2 = CHtml::link('View Details',array('view','id'=>$model->HEH_ID));
                                    //    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->HCO_ID));
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','You data have been saved successfully. '.$msg2);
                        $this->redirect(array('update','id'=>$model->HEH_ID));
                        }


                  }

                }

                $this->render('create',array(
                        'model'=>$model,'transport'=>$transport,
                    'member2'=>$member2,
                    'member'=>$member,
                   // 'validatedMembers2' => $validatedMembers2,
                    'validatedMembers' => $validatedMembers,
                ));
        }
```

**From View**

```
$memberFormConfig = array(
      'elements'=>array(

       'HED_RPASS'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>11,
        ),

        'HED_PCS'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>5,
        ),  
    ));


$this->widget('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm',array(
        'id' => 'id_member', //the unique widget id
        'formConfig' => $memberFormConfig, //the form configuration array
        'model' => $member, //instance of the form model
         'tableView' => true,
        //if submitted not empty from the controller,
        //the form will be rendered with validation errors
        'validatedItems' => $validatedMembers,
        //'sortAttribute' => 'position',
        //array of member instances loaded from db
        'data' => $member->findAll('HEH_ID=:HEH_ID', array(':HEH_ID'=>$model->HEH_ID)),
    ));



$memberFormConfig2 = array(
      'elements'=>array(
       'HED_ARV_PCS'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>5,
        ),
         'HED_ARV_VOL'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>10,
        ),  
    ));


$this->widget('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm',array(
        'id' => 'id_member2', //the unique widget id
        'formConfig' => $memberFormConfig2, //the form configuration array
        'model' => $member2, //instance of the form model
         'tableView' => true,
        //if submitted not empty from the controller,
        //the form will be rendered with validation errors
        'validatedItems' => $validatedMembers,
        //'sortAttribute' => 'position',
        //array of member instances loaded from db
        'data' => $member->findAll('HEH_ID=:HEH_ID', array(':HEH_ID'=>$model->HEH_ID)),
    ));
```

Comment: You can't do that. You have to customize their widget class to achieve what you want.

Comment: oh ic, thanks sir..i'm still newbie in yii, could someone give the example code how to customize that particular widget class. or maybe give some idea and example. I just want to create multi model in a single form and at the same time the related model members can be append and remove.(one to many,and the many model field can be append and remove). altogether will be save and update.